# Can we define the non-integer derivation of a function?

Tags: calculus

We know that  $\frac{d^{n}e^{x}}{dx^{n}}=e^{x}$. Can we define the $n$th derivation of $e^{x}$ which $n$ is a real number?!!!

Comment: Short answer: YES.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Honestly, I said him to fix it  frequently ,but nothing's appeared!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely! You can search for "fractional derivative" to find a lot of beginners and advanced oriented material. The general theory (i.e., not only fractional derivatives of $e^x$) not only makes sense mathematically but has many applications.

Comment: You can define what ever you want, how do you think definitions are created in the first place? someone defines them.

Comment: @Ethan: I find your comment cryptic. Evidently the question was not if one can give some arbitrary definition and call it a fractional derivative just for the fun of it. I find the OP shows healthy curiosity by considering the absolutely non-trivial question of whether the ordinary notion of derivative can be *extended* to include non-integer derivatives. The fact that the answer is relatively well-known to be yes does not diminish from the question and falls well inline with the purpose of this Q&A site.